# Error in retrieving the lenght of a string

Tags: java

What's wrong with my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Pali
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("\nInserisci una stringa: ");
      String p = in.next();

      int n = p.lenght();

   }      
}
```

I get a "cannot find symbol" error in p variable. Why? Many thanks (sorry,if I did something wrong, it's my first post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo:

```
int n = p.lenght();
```

Should be `p.length();`

Comment: D'oh, thanks a lot. Maybe it's time to put away the books and hit the bed

Answer (score 0):

Use: `int n = p.length();` instead of `p.lenght();`

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo.

```
int n = p.lenght();
```

Correction: `int n = p.length();`

It happens to the best of us.